# How does one add automatic nested resource routing for Symfony 2?

Tags: php, rest, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have to admit I am very new to Symfony. In fact, I just started a few hours ago.
I successfully did [this tutorial](http://voryx.net/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-easy-way/) and I wanted to see if it would also do nested routing automatically.

So I created another entity User (using FOSUserBundle) and I modified the entity Post to have a reference to the User. So now when I go to `http://localhost:8000/api/posts/1` I get this nice json:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "user":{     
        "id":1,
        "username":"Evert",
        "username_canonical":"evert",
        "email":"blabla@gmail.com",
        "email_canonical":"blabla@gmail.com",
        "enabled":true,
        "salt":"prxnqb681340c080g0k0g0owgkocsow",
        "password":"nTuI7GFL1yLIFlecWHHC58Lxi\/XjTu2dNoz4l3YGUuUhU+OH6JQFpv\/ojlfXOxoNmjgDdX9CsXTvzRGJi1PbzQ==",
        "last_login":"2014-10-18T23:25:04+0200",
        "locked":false,
        "expired":false,
        "roles":[],
        "credentials_expired":false
    },
    "name":"First!",
    "description":"Dus..."
}
```

Now I was hoping that if I would go to `http://localhost:8000/api/posts/1/user` that I would get to see the user that is connected to post, but by itself. However that's not the case. And I have tried to Google for how to do this, but I couldn't find anything. I think I could do it completely manually, but I would prefer if this nesting of resources is automatically available.

Can anybody tell me how I can make this routing work automatically for all related resources?